# how can i declare and use a namespace inside another namespace

Tags: xml, oxygenxml

this should be working but it says ml:math is incomplete and ml:matrix not allowed, how can i fix this ? i need to know if i can use a namespace inside another one

```
<!-- il est possible d'utiliser l'espace de noms http -->
<http:html xmlns:http="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<http:head>
    <http:title>Titre du document</http:title>
</http:head>
<http:body>
    <http:p>
        <!-- il est possible d'utiliser l'espace de noms ml -->
        <ml:math xmlns:ml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
            <ml:matrix>
                <ml:matrixrow>
                    <ml:cn>0</ml:cn>
                    <ml:cn>1</ml:cn>
                    <ml:cn>0</ml:cn>
                </ml:matrixrow>
                <ml:matrixrow>
                    <ml:cn>0</ml:cn>
                    <ml:cn>0</ml:cn>
                    <ml:cn>1</ml:cn>
                </ml:matrixrow>
            </ml:matrix>
        </ml:math>
        <!-- il n'est plus possible d'utiliser l'espace de noms ml -->
    </http:p>
</http:body>
</http:html>
<!-- il n'est plus possible d'utiliser l'espace de noms http -->
```

Comment: I think the issue is that the http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml doesn't allow you to extend it.  If you change that namespace to a custom one, it doesn't complain about it in Visual Studio.

Comment: when i change it to a custom one , it says elements for that  namespace are not allowed

Comment: What editing tool/dev tools are you using?

Comment: am using Oxygen